# How do I check if an object's FIELD exists in a list of the given object?

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have 2 classes one called Record and one called Location

```
public class Record
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
    public bool isDefault { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to check whether in a list of Locations whether the given ID from Record exists in the List of Locations. For example this is my code so far for handling. If field.Id does not exist in the current list then it should create a new Location and add it to the list.

```
foreach (Record field in inputs)
            {
                locationResponse = await myLocationCmd.GetLocation(locationInput).ConfigureAwait(false);
                
                foreach (Location locations in locationResponse.Locations)
                {
                        if (locations.IsDefault == true)
                        {
                            this.BadRequest();
                        }
                        else if (locations.IsDefault == false && // Check whether field.Id exists in locationResponse.Locations)
                        {
                            locationInput.Verb = CmdletVerb.Set.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (locations.IsDefault == false && // Check whether field.Id does not exist in the locationResponse.Locations)
                        {
                            locationInput.Verb = CmdletVerb.New.ToString();
                        }
                 
                }
```

Currently I tried doing `locationResponse.Locations.Contains(field.Id)` but this produces a type error. Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. The `Id` field always will exist, as a property of the object. It could be null, or empty string, though

Comment: What I am trying to convey is that each Location object in the list will have a LocationID. If that LocationId when compared to the field ID already exists in the list, then it will be a Set command. If the field ID when compared to the Location ID does not exist in the list then a new Location will be created and added to the list. I hope that is clearer

Comment: Shouldn't `GetLocation` be given an ID, which is then returned back as part of the response, so that all locations would already have the correct ID?

Comment: GetLocation takes another class that when supplied an Id returns all the Locations associated with that Id. It does not matter in this particular scenario right now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to loop over every object to check the ID

`locationResponse.Locations.Contains(field.Id)` gives a type error because that is a list of Locations, not a list of Strings

```
locationResponse = await myLocationCmd.GetLocation(locationInput).ConfigureAwait(false);

foreach (Record field in inputs) {
    var idExists = false;
    foreach (Location loc in locationResponse.Locations)
        idExists = loc.LocationId == field.Id;
        if (idExists) break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(idExists);
}
```

I would be cautious about the size of the `inputs` list, though, because you are looking over the same locations list more than once for every field, which is wasted iterations

Answer (score 0):

The shortest fix based on the given code would be using:

```
bool idExistsInList = locationResponse.Locations.Any(location => location.LocationId == field.Id);
```

And then you can use `idExistsInList` and `!idExistsInList` (respectively) in your two comments.

---

However, there are several further improvements to be made:

- There is a bug in your code. Your inner foreach keeps overwriting the same value and will effectively only keep the value that is set in the *last* loop of the `foreach`.
- The exact same bug happens for your outer `foreach`. The value of `locationInput.Verb` is effectively defined by comparing the *last* element of both lists, and all other evalutation are effectively overwritten.
- In general, favor LINQ over manual `foreach` logic. It enhances readability and cuts down on boilerplating.
- Assuming this is the only logic in the outer `foreach`, that can also be simplified using LINQ.
- For every input field, you fetch **the same** `locationResponse`. It makes no sense to do this for every field if the specific field value isn't actually used to fetch the object.
- There's no need for the third `if` evaluation. When the first two evaluations have failed, then the third one is *always* going to be true.
- `== true` can always be omitted.
- `== false` should generally be refactored to using `!`
- When you always set the same field/property, but a boolean value decided if you set it to one value or another, favor using the ternary `myBool ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse`.

You can extract this logic outside of the `foreach` loops:

```
var locationResponse = await myLocationCmd.GetLocation(locationInput).ConfigureAwait(false);

if(locationResponse.Locations.Any(location => location.IsDefault))
    this.BadRequest();

var locationIds = locationResponse.Locations.Select(location => location.LocationId).ToList();
```

How to handle the `foreach` loops is unclear, as I'm not sure whether you're trying to find if *any* field (= at least one) has a match in the location list, or whether *every* field has a match in the location list.

If you're trying to find if *any* field (= at least one) has a match in the location list:

```
bool matchFound = inputs.Any(field => locationIds.Contains(field.Id);
```

If you're trying to find if *every* field has a match in the location list:

```
bool matchFound = inputs.All(field => locationIds.Contains(field.Id);
```

`Any` returns `true` if at least one field has a match, `All` only returns `true` if  all fields have a match.

In either case, you can then continue on with:

```
locationInput.Verb = matchFound
                        ? CmdletVerb.Set.ToString()
                        : CmdletVerb.New.ToString();
```

And that accomplishes the same as your code, but with less redundancy and higher readability.